# How to get ID from CSS to Javascript without getElementByID?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a basic question involving CSS and JavaScript.

I have a page with several DIVs, each one with an unique ID taken from a mysql database. When a user clicks on a certain DIV, I want that one to disappear from the page. Because everything it's dynamic my solution was to pass the id as a variable to the function. The problem is I don't know how use that id. I need something to replace `document.getElementById()`.

JS:

```
function flashout(the_unique_id){
document.getElementByID(???).style.display = "";
}
```

HTML/CSS:

```
<div id="394" onclick="flashout(394)">...</div>
<div id="723" onclick="flashout(723)">...</div>
```

Comment: What's wrong with `document.getElementByID(the_unique_id)`?

Comment: And id can't be a number: ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Comment: @Edward: Those were HTML4 restrictions. Anyway, I'm pretty sure JavaScript implementations still successfully fetched by numeric id.

Comment: @LightStyle: That you've misspelled it: `…Id` :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ID should work but you don't have to use it. Just pass `this` as a parameter:

```
<div id="394" onclick="flashout(this)">...</div>
<div id="723" onclick="flashout(this)">...</div>
```

and use that param as a element itself instead of string ID:

```
function flashout(div_element){
   div_element.style.display = "none";
}
```

Oh and if you want DIV to disappear - set style.display to "none", not "".

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you are looking for.

When you you are establishing a function and its parameters in JavaScript, the parameter can be used like a variable while defining the function.  Try this

HTML:

```
<div id="394" onclick="flashout(394)">...</div>
<div id="723" onclick="flashout(723)">...</div>
```

JS:

```
function flashout(unique_id){
  document.getElementByID(unique_id).style.display = "";
}
```